# Wrong coded lazy initialization works well

Tags: objective-c, return-value, lazy-initialization

Is it intentionally that a mis-coded lazy init:

```
-(X*) prop {
    if (!prop) {
        prop = [[Prop alloc] init];
        return prop;
    }
    // RETURN SHOULD BE HERE 
}
```

nevertheless does 'the right thing' due to the generated code sequence below?

- loading prop into rax for the test
- returning rax in any case

Comment: I don't see anything called `rax` in that code.

Comment: @Bolt `RAX` is an x86_64 register.

Answer (score 4):

It is not intentional and, even if it works, you shouldn’t rely on that. For example, consider the following:

```
- (NSString *)someString {
    if (! someString) {
        someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", 5];
        return someString;
    }
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -O0`:

```
movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
movq    _OBJC_IVAR_$_SomeClass.someString@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
movq    (%rax), %rax
leaq    (%rdx,%rax), %rax
movq    (%rax), %rax
testq   %rax, %rax
```

and the code indeed works because, as you’ve noticed, the ivar is loaded into `RAX`.

However, when compiled with `gcc -O3`:

```
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    addq    _OBJC_IVAR_$_SomeClass.someString(%rip), %rbx
    cmpq    $0, (%rbx)
    je  L5
L4:
    movq    (%rsp), %rbx
    movq    8(%rsp), %r12
```

Oops, no return value in `RAX` — the ivar was loaded into `RBX`. This code works in the first call (the one that lazily initialises the ivar) but crashes in the second call.

Comment: And even if the compiler output was 100% dependable for this particular architecture, who is to say you won't need to recompile for another one down the line?

Comment: @walky: Ridiculous! Apple doesn't just go around switching architectures! I mean really! It's all PowerARMx868k, right?

Answer (score 2):

> is it intentionally, that a mis-coded lazy init:

No.

You're just lucky that the standard return register was used.  Don't ever rely on it.  In fact, it should give you a compiler warning.